# Qt Creator compile error for QSensor

Tags: qt, symbian, qt-creator

I'm new to Qt/Symbian development (I come from an iOS background), and I can't make sense of this compiler error:

Firstly, this is the error I'm getting:

```
/Users/Dave/AR-build-simulator/../QtSDK/Simulator/QtMobility/gcc/include/QtSensors/qsensor.h:-1: In member function 'QtMobility::QMagnetometerReading& QtMobility::QMagnetometerReading::operator=(const QtMobility::QMagnetometerReading&)':
```

Here is my header file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include <QSystemDeviceInfo>
#include <QGeoPositionInfoSource>
#include <QGeoCoordinate>
#include <QGeoPositionInfo>
#include <QMagnetometer>

QTM_USE_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum ScreenOrientation {
        ScreenOrientationLockPortrait,
        ScreenOrientationLockLandscape,
        ScreenOrientationAuto
    };

    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual ~MainWindow();

    // Note that this will only have an effect on Symbian and Fremantle.
    void setOrientation(ScreenOrientation orientation);

    void showExpanded();

private slots:
    void positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo gpsPos);
    void magnetometerReadingChanged(QMagnetometerReading mr);
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    void setupGeneral();

    QGeoPositionInfoSource *m_location;
    QGeoCoordinate m_coordinate;
    QMagnetometer *m_magnetometer;
    QMagnetometerReading m_magnetometerReading;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Here is the implementation file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <qgeopositioninfosource.h>
#include <QMessageBox>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setupGeneral();
}

void MainWindow::setupGeneral()
{
    m_location = QGeoPositionInfoSource::createDefaultSource(this);
    //Listen to gps position changes
    QObject::connect(m_location, SIGNAL(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)), this,SLOT(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)));

    //Start listening to GPS position updates
    m_location->startUpdates();

    //Start listening to magnetometer updates
    m_magnetometer = new QMagnetometer(this);
    connect(m_magnetometer, SIGNAL(readingChanged(QMagnetometerReading)), this, SLOT(magnetometerReadingChanged(QMagnetometerReading)));
    m_magnetometer->start();
}

void MainWindow::positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo gpsPos){
     m_coordinate = gpsPos.coordinate();
     if (m_coordinate.isValid()) {
            m_location->stopUpdates();
            QString longitude;
            QString latitude;
            longitude.setNum(m_coordinate.longitude());
            latitude.setNum(m_coordinate.latitude());
            QMessageBox::information(this,"latitude",latitude);
     } else {
            QMessageBox::information(this, "GPS Info", "Coordinator is not valid...");
     }
}

void MainWindow::magnetometerReadingChanged(QMagnetometerReading mr) {
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Magnetometer info", "got magnetometer reading...");
    m_magnetometerReading = mr;
    //m_magnetometerReading = new QMagnetometerReading(this);
    //m_magnetometerReading->copyValuesFrom(mr);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::setOrientation(ScreenOrientation orientation)
{
#if defined(Q_OS_SYMBIAN)
    // If the version of Qt on the device is < 4.7.2, that attribute won't work
    if (orientation != ScreenOrientationAuto) {
        const QStringList v = QString::fromAscii(qVersion()).split(QLatin1Char('.'));
        if (v.count() == 3 && (v.at(0).toInt() << 16 | v.at(1).toInt() << 8 | v.at(2).toInt()) < 0x040702) {
            qWarning("Screen orientation locking only supported with Qt 4.7.2 and above");
            return;
        }
    }
#endif // Q_OS_SYMBIAN

    Qt::WidgetAttribute attribute;
    switch (orientation) {
#if QT_VERSION < 0x040702
    // Qt < 4.7.2 does not yet have the Qt::WA_*Orientation attributes
    case ScreenOrientationLockPortrait:
        attribute = static_cast<Qt::WidgetAttribute>(128);
        break;
    case ScreenOrientationLockLandscape:
        attribute = static_cast<Qt::WidgetAttribute>(129);
        break;
    default:
    case ScreenOrientationAuto:
        attribute = static_cast<Qt::WidgetAttribute>(130);
        break;
#else // QT_VERSION < 0x040702
    case ScreenOrientationLockPortrait:
        attribute = Qt::WA_LockPortraitOrientation;
        break;
    case ScreenOrientationLockLandscape:
        attribute = Qt::WA_LockLandscapeOrientation;
        break;
    default:
    case ScreenOrientationAuto:
        attribute = Qt::WA_AutoOrientation;
        break;
#endif // QT_VERSION < 0x040702
    };
    setAttribute(attribute, true);
}

void MainWindow::showExpanded()
{
#ifdef Q_OS_SYMBIAN
    showFullScreen();
#elif defined(Q_WS_MAEMO_5)
    showMaximized();
#else
    show();
#endif
}
```

If anybody could explain to me what is going wrong, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Could you post the full error?

Comment: here is the full error: /Users/Dave/AR-build-simulator/../QtSDK/Simulator/QtMobility/gcc/include/QtSensors/qsensor.h:-1: In member function 'QtMobility::QMagnetometerReading& QtMobility::QMagnetometerReading::operator=(const QtMobility::QMagnetometerReading&)':

Comment: /Users/Dave/AR-build-simulator/../QtSDK/Simulator/QtMobility/gcc/include/QtSensors/qsensor.h:199: error: 'QtMobility::QSensorReading& QtMobility::QSensorReading::operator=(const QtMobility::QSensorReading&)' is private

Comment: /Users/Dave/AR-build-simulator/../QtSDK/Simulator/QtMobility/gcc/include/QtSensors/qmagnetometer.h:52: error: within this context

Comment: /Users/Dave/AR-build-simulator/../QtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/include/QtCore/qscopedpointer.h:170: error: 'QScopedPointer<T, Cleanup>& QScopedPointer<T, Cleanup>::operator=(const QScopedPointer<T, Cleanup>&) [with T = QtMobility::QMagnetometerReadingPrivate, Cleanup = QScopedPointerDeleter<QtMobility::QMagnetometerReadingPrivate>]' is private

Comment: /Users/Dave/AR-build-simulator/../QtSDK/Simulator/QtMobility/gcc/include/QtSensors/qmagnetometer.h:52: error: within this context

Comment: /Users/Dave/AR-build-simulator/../AR/mainwindow.cpp:-1: In member function 'void MainWindow::magnetometerReadingChanged(QtMobility::QMagnetometerReading&)':

Comment: /Users/Dave/AR-build-simulator/../AR/mainwindow.cpp:46: synthesized method 'QtMobility::QMagnetometerReading& QtMobility::QMagnetometerReading::operator=(const QtMobility::QMagnetometerReading&)' first required here

Comment: Please DON'T put this in the comments. Put it in your question. You can edit it. See the "edit" link at the bottom, below the question tags. Remove these errors from the comments.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation([here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/qsensor.html#readingChanged)) `readingChanged` signal does not have any parameters. You should use

`connect(m_magnetometer, SIGNAL(readingChanged()), this, SLOT(magnetometerReadingChanged()));` and then acquire the reading from the `reading` property.